# Understanding CT sensors and current to voltage circuits

Tags: current-source, current-transformer

I have difficulties to wrap my head around the concept of CT sensors ([SCT-013-000](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/sites/default/files/current100a.jpg) f.e.).
I currently want to improve the current to voltage circuit I use with the usage of an op amp. While I can just copy the existing circuit designs out there and use them I would rather have a deeper understanding.

From what I understand the coil in the "sensor" is getting current induced by the AC phase I clamp it onto.
Though I don't have any voltage which weirds me out, do I just have electrons just sitting around in the coil? Where do they go? Can I build up a lethal amount of current by not connecting it to a circuit?

Apparently I need a so called burden resistor across both ends of the CT sensor to get a voltage but how does that work? Why does a resistor make electrons flow all of the sudden?

How can I use this CT sensor that gives me current but no voltage without violating ohms law? I get more amps all of the sudden than my power supply is delivering to the circuit. Or is my PSU delivering an equal amount less than gets induced by the CT sensor?

I'm deeply confused by this concept of a current only source and how I can turn this current into an equivalent voltage, maybe someone can shed some light on this for me.

Comment: Related: apparently another name for "current transformer" is [AC current sensor](http://www.opencircuits.com/AC_current_sensor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I understand the coil in the "sensor" is getting current
>   induced by the AC phase I clamp it onto.

The current in the clamped AC circuit induces a voltage in the main coil (the secondary winding) of the CT. The current that flows in the secondary winding is only due to adding a burden resistor to the terminals of that coil.

Without a burden resistor, the voltage at the terminals of the secondary can be several tens of volts in amplitude because, in effect the primary is 1 turn and the secondary is (say) a thousand turns and although this makes a voltage magnification of 1000:1 the voltage at the primary is only a few several millivolts. That's the story without a burden resistor.

Just as the CT will magnify voltage by 1000:1 conservation of energy means that it reduces current into the secondary by 1000:1 but only when a burden resistor is added.

There are other subtleties related to how the burden (on the secondary) is transformed down into a very low impedance on the primary by the turns ratio squared and understanding this gives a real deep insight into the mechanisms at play but try and understand what I wrote above first.

Comment: I thought I had no voltage at all in my CT? Is that misinformation? If understand correctly what you say is that I get current and a voltage from the AC circuit?
So the burden resistor is only there to close the circuit?

Comment: Yeah there's still some (very) small voltage drop.

Comment: It is misinformation.

Comment: Yes, you normally get a current and a voltage from the current transformer, the same as any other transformer.